# Is it actually incorrect to follow certain verbs with a that-clause?

Tags: clauses, that

I found a [webpage](https://www.englishgrammar.org/verbs-object-infinitive/) saying certain verbs are followed by infinitives rather than that-clauses.  However, is it actually incorrect to use a that-clause with certain verbs, for example, with the verb "request"?

Example:  I request that you come with me.

Request is a transitive verb, which can take that-clauses as a direct object.  So why would this example be incorrect?  Or is it only non-standard but still correct?  Another verb that fits this is "allow".

Example:  I allow that they stay up until 10pm.

If this is actually incorrect, what and where is the rule?  Is there some authority or rule book with the rules?  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, the rule is that there is no rule. You have to learn what type(s) of complement each verb licenses individually. Your example with _request_ is perfectly grammatical and not non-standard at all, but the one with _allow_ is highly unusual – unless you’re using _allow_ to mean ‘concede, acknowledge’, in which case it’s standard fare. Even a single verb can require different treatments in different senses.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for your quick answer.  So if there is no rule, then that would seem to imply it is correct, right?

Comment: "I request that you [do something]" sound fine to me, better than "I request you [do something]". The *allow* example sounds clumsy at best, I would say "I allow them to stay up until 10 pm".

Comment: “No rule” doesn’t mean that anything goes. It means that each verb behaves differently, so you cannot apply a general rule.

Comment: Thank you everyone!  So is the behavior of certain verbs a rule itself, or just standard usage that does not have to be followed?  @Xanne

Comment: How do you define “rule”?  Something that must be followed 100% of the time? Or what? What happens if it’s not followed?  Or something that must be followed but only when it’s applicable? In that case everything’s a “rule”?  What’s your definition?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with either of your examples. I would say the second one is fairly uncommon today—but it's certainly not wrong. *I allow that* was much more common [in the past](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+allow+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20allow%20that%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20allow%20that%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I just mean is it absolutely required not to use a that-clause in certain cases with some verbs that normally take an infinitive or something else.  Will the grammar still be considered correct if the that-clause is used even if it is non-standard?  @Jim

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification, much appreciated!  @JasonBassford